# Is using the .contains function to include spaces possible?

Tags: java, string, filereader

Here is my scenario.

I'm searching a text file for a line, but I'm not giving it the exact match, so I'm using the .contains() function to check for a line that simply contains the string, but it ignores white spaces.

For example, if I search for "The Unbearable Likeness" in a file that contains

```
"The Dark Knight"
"The First Ones"
"The Unbearable Likeness Of Being"
```

then it simply returns the first line, as it ignores the space. Is there a way to get it to recognise the space?

Comment: Which space are you talking about?

Comment: I don't understand your example. Why would it return the first line? Which space are you talking about?

Comment: What is your code? Do you go through all the lines from the `string[]` array with a `for` loop?

Comment: I'm using a while loop. If I search for "The Unbearable Likeness" it returns the first line that contains "the".

Comment: Don't use a `while` loop then. Use a `for` loop and its size limit should be the array length.

Comment: Instead of talking *about* your code, how about showing it in your question?

Answer (score 0):

The `contains()` method does not exclude spaces or anything like that. It only returns true if the whole string is contained. It's easy to demonstrate:

```
System.out.println("Fred Bloggs".contains("red"));
System.out.println("Fred Bloggs".contains("Fred Bloggs"));
System.out.println("Fred Bloggs".contains("Fred Bloggs II"));
System.out.println("Fred Bloggs".contains("Fred Blags"));
```

Prints:

```
true
true
false
false
```

For your case, a `for` loop might work:

```
String searchString = "The Unbearable Likeness";

String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("titles.txt")), "UTF-8");
String[] titles = content.split("[\r\n]");
for (String title: titles) {
    if (title.contains(searchString)) {
        System.out.print("Found match: " + title);
    }
}
```

This loads the titles from the file `titles.txt`, splits into lines,  iterates over them and prints a message when the title contains the search string.